# template for python function that created modified version of input, but does not modify input

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, deep-copy, pass-by-value

The majority of my programming experience in in the R language and I am now doing a python project.  I want to make a function that kind of works like an R function in that it takes an object and returns an object that is similar, but changed in some way and the initial object remains in the calling namespace unchanged.  My "template" for doing this is...

```
from copy import deepcopy
def cut_in_half(l):
    l_new = deepcopy(l)
    l_new = l_new[range(ceil(len(l_new)/2))]
    return l_new
```

This is a toy example, but the main idea is that I start by making a deepcopy and then modifying that and then returning that.  This feels a bit clunky and I can't help but wondering if I am doing something wrong. Am I?

Comment: It is a bit clunky. I think the question is what you're trying to preserve, either in the original object or from the original object in the new object. If the objects are being used in different ways, then what about adding another member to the object that contains the modified data? Or, if they're being used in the same way but at different times, can you use the original object, then modify it and use the modified object later?

Comment: Usually the copy is done in the calling code, just before or when passing the function argument. This makes explicit that you are making and passing a copy (preserving the original) and avoids errors by side effect, because the function simply cannot change the original object.